# Expanding data vault for new requirements

Tags: database, data-vault

**Environment:**
I have a hub table for logging information about processes. The hub contains start time, end time, success/failure of the process.

**Desired change:**
Some of the processes receive a list of work items. I'd like to capture counts for those processes where it makes sense.

What is the "correct" way to accomplish this? I assume I add a new table joined to the hub? What is the data vault 2.0 term for this table?

Comment: First, make sure you understand what a hub is.  A hub is only a list of business key to represent a business entity, and a business key a what users can memorize to retrieve information (like a process name, an work item name, ....).  Satellite will keep attributes of thoses business key (like status of the process)  and Link will model relation between business entities

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_vault_modeling

Comment: So my "hub" table could be a unique list of the names of processes. A "satellite" table would contain information about when a process was run, what the result was, etc. ?

Comment: basically, if the process name is a business key, yes, otherwise no. For the satellites, it contains attributes of the business entity (hub). You can have more than one satellites for a particular hub.  And then, there's the link table that model the relation between hub.  Please read the basis :  https://danlinstedt.com/solutions-2/data-vault-basics/  and pay attention to the 1st cut logical data model picture. Notice there is only one non-system field in the hub, InvoiceID for the hub Invoice, and ProductId for the product.

Comment: The problem with reading docs about data vaults is the definitions use terms only understood by data scientists. Almost none of the articles are anything but copy and paste. Then there are two very different "standards" which the reader may not know about and the writers seldom mention. They know what they're talking about but the readers don't.

Comment: two different standards?  There's datavault 2.0.... and what is the other one?